# apache drill - does it support mysql inner join with same storage plugin

Tags: mysql, apache-drill

running apache-drill-1.14.0

storage plugin1 : myplugin

```
SELECT t1.id FROM myplugin.db.t1, myplugin.db.t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 12345 GROUP BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id;
```

inner join with another table in the same database returns - Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AssertionError: Relational expression

creating another storage plugin2 : myplugin2 (copy of plugin1)

```
SELECT t1.id FROM myplugin.db.t1, myplugin2.db.t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id AND t2.id = 12345 GROUP BY t1.id ORDER BY t1.id;
```

working fine

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was resolved in scope of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6850

Please check on Drill [master branch](https://github.com/apache/drill) (see [help](http://drill.apache.org/docs/compiling-drill-from-source/#2-compile-the-code)) or wait for a new 1.15.0 Drill release.

```
mysql> select t1.`PersonId` from testdb.`mscIdentities3` t1 join testdb.`mscIdentities3` t2 on t1.`PersonId` = t2.`PersonID` where t1.`PersonID` = 10;
+----------+
| PersonId |
+----------+
|       10 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.00 sec)

0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> select t1.`PersonId` from mysql.testdb.`mscIdentities3` t1 join mysql.testdb.`mscIdentities3` t2 on t1.`PersonId` = t2.`PersonID` where t1.`PersonID` = 10;
+-----------+
| PersonId  |
+-----------+
| 10        |
+-----------+
1 row selected (1.166 seconds)
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the reply, i was able to get current master and it is working fine with current master in git : apache-drill-1.15.0

Comment: Hi Manoj Kumar. In the process of investigating your case I found the issue, could you please take a look and confirm it exists: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-6893
Thank you.